# Extracting text after before and after a | using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In my efforts to build something like stackoverflows linking system I was trying to do something like this;

```
$raw = '[[path.html|Link description]]';

$str = preg_replace('#\[(\?)|(\?)]#', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $raw);

echo $str;
//$str should not be <a href="path.html">Link description</a>
```

This should have worked, but I keep getting the same text as my output. My idea is to put the part before the `|` as the `href` and the one after the `|` as the link description. In the end, I just have fail.

I took this from a woking example, but I'm stuck after adding the `|` part.

Comment: `|` means “OR” in regular expressions – if you want a _literal_ `|`, then you have to mask it with a backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem on your regex was that you hadn't escaped the `|` so you were having an `OR` expression.

You can use this regex:

```
\[\[(.*?)\|(.*?)\]\]
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/jE4aJ9/1)**

[image]

Comment: Works well. Is it possible to build the regex to work with or without the second part? So if that part were blank it'll still work `[[path.jpg]] = <img src="path.jpg" title="">`. Right now, without that part it wont do any matching. I plan on implementing it differently. Just used the above for this example.

Answer (score 1):

Just escape the pipe:

```
$str = preg_replace('#\[(.+?)\|(.+?)\]#', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $raw);
```

`\?` matches literally a question mark. Change your regex like above.